# Same entity name in two different entity frameworks

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have an MVC application using Entity Framework 4.1.

I am connecting to two different databases from this application, so I created two different .edmx files in my project.  These edmx files have different container names and different namespaces.  They both have a table with the same name (and same field definitions) that I want to use in my application.

When I add that entity into both models, my application will not compile.  I recieve a "multiple definitions with identical signatures" error.

Do I have to rename the entities in order to accomplish this?

Thanks!

-Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't support multiple classes with the same name in the same assembly regardless of what namespace those classes are in. You can use different names for the entities or separate them into separate assemblies.